# jquery autocompletebox isn't working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm playing around with ASP.NET and jquery in an attempt to learn it, and right now I'm working on an autocomplete textbox, but with little luck. I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78704/Different-Approaches-for-Implementing-the-JQuery) and the example code on the [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) page, but something isn't working right. I've installed both jquery and jquery-ui using NuGet.

This is the code I've tried, any obvious problems?

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input#TextBoxAutoComplete").autocomplete({
            source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
        });
    })
</script>

<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxAutoComplete" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
```

Comment: did you also add the jQuery UI css

Comment: @ArunPJohny Oh hey I didn't, I didn't realize it was required. Let me try that

Comment: can you check the generated html to see whether what is correct id of the element, also check whether there are any error in your browser console.... it is working otherwise http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dtGnQ/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny I checked the html and see that the id was changed, so I made it static. I'm getting the css in there now

Comment: @ArunPJohny Still doesn't work. I've updated my code to its current state

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: @ArunPJohny That helped, it wasn't able to load my script and css reference. They needed to start with /

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm very much a novice with ASP.NET, jquery, and web development in general. I appreciate the help

Comment: I'll post it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments

1. Include the jQuery-ui.css file
2. Check the generated input element's id... use a static id if required
3. Check whether the path to the script/style files are correct

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$('#<%= TextBoxAutoComplete.ClientID %>').autocomplete({...
```

or:

```
$('[id$=TextBoxAutoComplete]').autocomplete({...
```

instead of:

```
$("input#TextBoxAutoComplete").autocomplete({...
```